# why wont the computer recognize gets()

Tags: c++, string, c++20, cstdio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[100];
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    gets(str);
    cout << "You entered: " << str;

    return 0; 
}
```

This is code sample has been coppied exactly form programiz.com and i have no idea how this works I am learning c++ and i wanted to see how the gets function works in action.
whenever i try to run this code it says that the identifier is unidentified...
I think that either the header cstdio or the function gets has been outdated, but there must be some way to access a string with whitespaces...
please help.

Comment: It's been removed from the language for good reasons. It's impossible to use it safely.

Comment: As such, I think the correct solution to this problem is to stop reading programiz.com if they are going to present such bad examples.

Comment: Proper material to learn C++ from are for example [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: And the proper solution for C++ is to use `std::string` from `<string>` instead of `char[100]` as string type and then [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will allow you to read a full line of input regardless of whitespace it contains.

Comment: @NateEldredge To their credit, it turns out the example is actually only on their reference page for `gets` and a note specifically says that the function shouldn't be used for security concerns and has been removed since C++14, which makes me wonder what OP expected if they know they are specifically using C++20. (https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdio/gets)

Comment: Correct code should look something like this: [https://ideone.com/aIVJGv](https://ideone.com/aIVJGv)